# mongodump inside docker doesn't create any files

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm using docker to host mongo database and now I'm trying to dump the whole database. Everything is working fine, except no files are created. No errors at all. 
This is what I tried:

```
docker exec -ti mongodb mongodump --out /backup --host localhost -u admin -p admin
```

I'm using `tutum/mongodb` image from DockerHub.
This is full log after execution of that command: http://pastebin.com/SXCqv16v

EDIT:
output of `docker inspect mongodb`: http://pastebin.com/5sdheAwK

my docker-compose.yml file: http://pastebin.com/JmfKbtdJ

Comment: It's writing the backup out to /backup _inside_ the docker container unless you shared that volume when you started the mongo docker. Can you send the docker run command or the output of `docker inspect mongodb`

Comment: @JamieMcCrindle I've updated my question

Comment: the backup is being written but it's being written inside the container. I'm assuming you want it outside of docker? e.g. in the /backup directory of the docker host

Comment: @JamieMcCrindle Yes, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to map the /backup directory to a volume on the docker host. Change your docker compose mongodb entry to (replace /hostbackupdir with the appropriate folder on the host)

```
mongodb:
  image: tutum/mongodb
  environment:
    - MONGODB_PASS=admin
    - MONGODB_USER=admin
  container_name: mongodb
  volumes:
    - /hostbackupdir:/backup
```

Note: it's probably not a bad idea to also map your /data/db directory to one on your host too. that would be something like (replace /hostbackupdir and /hostdatadir with the appropriate folders on the host):

```
mongodb:
  image: tutum/mongodb
  environment:
    - MONGODB_PASS=admin
    - MONGODB_USER=admin
  container_name: mongodb
  volumes:
    - /hostbackupdir:/backup
    - /hostdatadir:/data/db
```

Comment: Not working, I created /backup folder inside host and update docker-compose as you instructed but /backup directory is empty

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. The problem was in binding the host folder with container folder:

```
mongodb:
  image: tutum/mongodb
  environment:
    - MONGODB_PASS=admin
    - MONGODB_USER=admin
  container_name: mongodb
  volumes:
    - ../backup:/backup
```